# Execute a pentaho kettle (.ktr) using python

Tags: python, pentaho, kettle

I have a .ktr file to execute where I can not use spoon or any other tool to execute it.

How to execute that ktr file using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t. The execution relies on a product developer by Hitachi Vantara, so unless you take all the source code from their repository and convert that to Python, the only way you have to execute a Pentaho transformation is to use their tools.

Either way, you can create a python application that calls on Pentaho's tools to execute the transformation you need.

The console application used to run a .ktr file is "Pan".